# Using x:Static expression with ConverterParameter property

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've seen examples of the "x:Static" expression being used to specify the ConverterParameter property of a binding in WPF XAML.  However, as far as I can tell, Xamarin will not allow you to set the property in this way.  Specifying the ConverterParameter in the code behind works fine, using a StaticResource expression works fine, using a literal value, fine.  Could someone please point me to an example of this being done in Xamarin?

My XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OMS.ProductionPickupPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OMS;assembly=OMS"
             Title="Production Pickup"
             Padding="5,5,5,5">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:PickerIndexConverter x:Key="PickerConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
<Picker x:Name="LoadingFacility_Picker" Title="Loading Facility" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedLoadingFacility, Mode=OneWayToSource, 
Converter={StaticResource PickerConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:TestClass.TestMember}}" />
```

This is the exception thrown by the LoadFromXml method in InitializeComponent():

```cs
System.Exception: Property  is not valid for this Expression

Stack Trace:

[External Code] 
0xC in OMS.ProductionPickupPage.InitializeComponent at e:\Workspace\sumrallj\OMS\OMS\OMS\obj\Debug\ProductionPickupPage.xaml.g.cs:42,-1 C#
0x14 in OMS.ProductionPickupPage..ctor at e:\Workspace\sumrallj\OMS\OMS\OMS\ProductionPickupPage.xaml.cs:17,-1  C#
0x1 in OMS.App.GetMainPage at e:\Workspace\sumrallj\OMS\OMS\OMS\App.cs:14,-1    C#
0x22 in OMS.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching at e:\Workspace\sumrallj\OMS\OMS\OMS.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:34,-1 C#
0xB in MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main at /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62,4  C#
0x3B in MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main at /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46,4 C#
0x8 in OMS.iOS.Application.Main at e:\Workspace\sumrallj\OMS\OMS\OMS.iOS\Main.cs:17,-1  C#
```

TestClass and TestMember are both static and I've also tried this with an enum.

```cs
namespace OMS
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static string TestMember = "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing should works just fine. The exception thrown is very unfamiliar. Could you please add a more complete stack trace ? and also share your OMS.TestClass.TestMemeber ? tx

Comment: Note that the exception message contains an extra space between "Property" and "is not valid".  It's like there's suppose to be a property name inserted there but for some reason it's blank.  Maybe a clue.

Comment: I created a new Xamarin.Forms solution with a single page.  On the page is a single Label with the Text property bound using x:Static to a static string property.  I'm getting an exception saying that no static member was found for my test member.  There has to be something obvious that I'm missing.